# Are there dependable findings regarding the "SLOC vs. handled workload" ratio?

Tags: metrics, reproducible-research

I came to ponder about sentences like "80% of the work is done by 20% of the code" and wondered if there are any underlying studies, principles or research that would support such a statement.

Sadly my Google-Fu was not sufficient to come up with a satisfying answer.
All that popped up was the [Pareto principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle), but I am not sure if it can be applied in this case.

1. Is there any general concensus about the ratio of handled workload towards the ratio of SLOC?
2. Has anyone done research on this topic or are there statistics available to support any claims?
3. Are there general statements to be made about which kind of code falls into which kind of category? (My initial guess here was that the *80% code / 20% load* sections are mostly related to error handling.)

Comment: It may be true that 80% of the work (measured dynamically) is done by 20% of the code, or some similar lopsided ratio.   The problem is whether the 20% does anything useful at all (yes, dead code exists in all big systems), or is critical to program function and just runs rarely, e.g., an error handler or a leap-year adjustment.   What is the point of your question?

Comment: I intuitively concur that there is this ratio. But how great is it? Has anyone measured it, or are there range estimations like ~90% - 70% vs 10% - 30%. Are there any experiences out there that quantify these ratios or are they all around the ballpark?

Comment: Sure.  Go run any profiler on an entire application.   Most of the code will be cold.   Some small part will be hot.  The rest of the code... cool.

Comment: Exactly. We are getting there. Now, over a large number of relevant projects, how much of the code is 'hot' and how 'hot' is it?The question is not about the existence of this effect or how to measure it, its about deriving a rule, a **quantification** of this effect (thats part 1). Of course I can now start to profile dozens of projects, but I am fairly sure somebody else might already have done so (that's part 2).  Finally, is there any possible generalization about which kinds of code cause this effect (thats part 3)?

Answer (score 1):

OP wants to see typical profiling numbers.   Here's a sample for our parallel program analysis tool CloneDR, that finds duplicated code across large programs (in this case across 77,000 lines of COBOL code, taking 284 seconds wall clock time with 6 CPUs loaded at about 95%):

```
C:\DMS\Domains\COBOL\IBMEnterprise\Tools\CloneDR>C:\dms\domains\PARLANSE\Tools\RunTimeSystem\run C:\DMS\Domains\PARLANSE\Tools\RunTimeSystem\StackTraceViewer.P0B CloneDR.std
Loading file C:/DMS/Domains/COBOL/IBMEnterprise/Tools/CloneDR/CloneDR.std
STACK TRACE: CloneDR.p0b
Loading 383 filename references.
Loading 138 foreign function entries.
Loading 107 runtime system entries.
Loading 65,815 stack trace samples.
         0.........
   100,000..
Read 1567 individual file/lines
Read 129,746 total lines
Removing direct recursion...
Calculating individual counts
Function info count: 490
Missed count: 0
Finished loading file C:/DMS/Domains/COBOL/IBMEnterprise/Tools/CloneDR/CloneDR.std
    Lines processed:  129,746
    Trace nodes:          490
    Recursive nodes:   66,025
    Call tree nodes:  129,110
    Max call depth:     2,161
Matching isomorphic trees for 490 trace nodes...
Found 46,016 isomorphic trees in 1,158 sets
----------------
* Busiest Isomorphic Trees (cutoff at  1.00%)
----------------
        8,274 ( 7,452 |     1) ( 12.6%):                   GetFirstChild [2661]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
GetFirstChild
        5,886 ( 4,859 |     1) (  8.9%):                  GetSecondChild [2683]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
GetSecondChild
        5,646 (   505 |     1) (  8.6%):                          Lookup [377]:c:/DMS/Domains/PARLANSE/Library/HashTables/Hash.par
Lookup
        5,332 ( 4,871 |     1) (  8.1%):                      EqualNodes [4653]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
EqualNodes
        3,354 ( 2,615 |     1) (  5.1%):             GetNthChildStandard [2516]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
GetNthChildStandard
        3,320 ( 3,208 |     1) (  5.0%):                      IsListNode [2137]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
IsListNode
        2,873 ( 2,723 |     1) (  4.4%):                 GetNthChildList [2578]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
GetNthChildList
        2,656 (    22 |     1) (  4.0%):                       Subsumes? [1215]:C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Tuple.par
Subsumes?
        2,342 (   998 |     1) (  3.6%):                 IsSequenceSpine [254]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ALSTInterface.par
IsSequenceSpine
        2,203 (   706 |     1) (  3.3%):                     GetNthChild [1068]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ALSTInterface.par
GetNthChild
        2,159 ( 2,077 |     1) (  3.3%):        NumberOfStandardChildren [2347]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
NumberOfStandardChildren
        2,017 ( 1,894 |     1) (  3.1%):              GetNodeLiteralType [5904]:c:/DMS/Infrastructure/HyperGraph/Source/Graph.par
GetNodeLiteralType
        1,901 ( 1,748 |     2) (  2.9%):                      EqualNodes [4653]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
(EqualNodes GetNodeLiteralType)
        1,836 ( 1,657 |     1) (  2.8%):            NumberOfChildrenList [2372]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
NumberOfChildrenList
        1,041 (   501 |     1) (  1.6%):                NumberOfChildren [2517]:c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ALSTInterface.par
NumberOfChildren
          771 (   363 |     1) (  1.2%):  FollowSequenceNodePortNthToNode [5369]:c:/DMS/Infrastructure/HyperGraph/Source/Graph.par
FollowSequenceNodePortNthToNode
          658 (     7 |     1) (  1.0%):       AppendNodeToCandidateList [1101]:C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/TupleCloneDetector.par
AppendNodeToCandidateList
----------------
* Busiest functions with more than  1.00% of total runtime (excluding children)
----------------
       8,274/ 12.6%: (GetFirstChild) Line 2661 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       5,886/  8.9%: (GetSecondChild) Line 2683 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       5,686/  8.6%: (Lookup) Line 377 File 331 c:/DMS/Domains/PARLANSE/Library/HashTables/Hash.par
       5,588/  8.5%: (EqualNodes) Line 4653 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       3,354/  5.1%: (GetNthChildStandard) Line 2516 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       3,335/  5.1%: (IsListNode) Line 2137 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       2,873/  4.4%: (GetNthChildList) Line 2578 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       2,656/  4.0%: (Subsumes?) Line 1215 File 346 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Tuple.par
       2,342/  3.6%: (IsSequenceSpine) Line 254 File 329 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ALSTInterface.par
       2,293/  3.5%: (GetNthChild) Line 1068 File 329 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ALSTInterface.par
       2,159/  3.3%: (NumberOfStandardChildren) Line 2347 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       2,017/  3.1%: (GetNodeLiteralType) Line 5904 File 52 c:/DMS/Infrastructure/HyperGraph/Source/Graph.par
       1,836/  2.8%: (NumberOfChildrenList) Line 2372 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       1,108/  1.7%: (NumberOfChildren) Line 2517 File 329 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ALSTInterface.par
         829/  1.3%: (ComputeSimilaritySubtreePairFast) Line 972 File 337 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/NodeSimilarity.par
         771/  1.2%: (FollowSequenceNodePortNthToNode) Line 5369 File 52 c:/DMS/Infrastructure/HyperGraph/Source/Graph.par
----------------
* Busiest Functions with more than  1.00% of total runtime (including children)
----------------
      64,707/ 98.3%: (RTS: Unclassifiable code) Line 1 File 65532
      60,105/ 91.3%: (GeneralizeTuple) Line 1323 File 371 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/TupleCloneDetector.par
      46,195/ 70.2%: (ComputeSimilaritySelfTrees) Line 1010 File 346 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Tuple.par
      46,192/ 70.2%: (ComputeSimilarityWithProposedAddition) Line 1133 File 346 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Tuple.par
      39,982/ 60.7%: (CD_EqualTrees) Line 198 File 333 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Misc.par
      25,810/ 39.2%: (ComputeSimilaritySelfSequenceElement) Line 824 File 346 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Tuple.par
      25,782/ 39.2%: (ComputeSimilarityTreeVector) Line 384 File 346 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Tuple.par
      20,823/ 31.6%: (ComputeSimilarityTreePairFast) Line 1248 File 337 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/NodeSimilarity.par
      17,610/ 26.8%: (ComputeSimilaritySubtreePairFast) Line 972 File 337 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/NodeSimilarity.par
       8,274/ 12.6%: (GetFirstChild) Line 2661 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       7,791/ 11.8%: (EqualTreesUseSignatures) Line 577 File 337 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/NodeSimilarity.par
       7,634/ 11.6%: (EqualNodes) Line 4653 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       7,543/ 11.5%: (ContainsIdenticalTreeClone) Line 2911 File 346 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Tuple.par
       6,118/  9.3%: (Lookup) Line 377 File 331 c:/DMS/Domains/PARLANSE/Library/HashTables/Hash.par
       5,886/  8.9%: (GetSecondChild) Line 2683 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       4,345/  6.6%: (???) Line 2696 File 3 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/CloneDR.par
       3,940/  6.0%: (GetNthChild) Line 1068 File 329 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ALSTInterface.par
       3,865/  5.9%: (InitializeSingleton) Line 1757 File 346 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Tuple.par
       3,853/  5.9%: (CD_GetNodeCount) Line 97 File 333 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Misc.par
       3,853/  5.9%: (GetNodeCountAuxiliary) Line 88 File 333 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Misc.par
       3,829/  5.8%: (???) Line 2367 File 3 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/CloneDR.par
       3,829/  5.8%: (DetectClones) Line 1912 File 371 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/TupleCloneDetector.par
       3,808/  5.8%: (AddSingletonTuple) Line 1070 File 372 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/TupleSet.par
       3,799/  5.8%: (NewTupleSingleton) Line 1773 File 346 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Tuple.par
       3,733/  5.7%: (IsListNode) Line 2137 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       3,555/  5.4%: (ProcessTuples) Line 1710 File 371 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/TupleCloneDetector.par
       3,354/  5.1%: (GetNthChildStandard) Line 2516 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       2,873/  4.4%: (GetNthChildList) Line 2578 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       2,656/  4.0%: (Subsumes?) Line 1215 File 346 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/Tuple.par
       2,624/  4.0%: (NumberOfChildren) Line 2517 File 329 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ALSTInterface.par
       2,342/  3.6%: (IsSequenceSpine) Line 254 File 329 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ALSTInterface.par
       2,159/  3.3%: (NumberOfStandardChildren) Line 2347 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       2,017/  3.1%: (GetNodeLiteralType) Line 5904 File 52 c:/DMS/Infrastructure/HyperGraph/Source/Graph.par
       1,963/  3.0%: (GetNodeCountFast) Line 165 File 328 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/TreeProperties.par
       1,836/  2.8%: (NumberOfChildrenList) Line 2372 File 95 c:/DMS/Domains/DMSStringGrammar/Tools/DomainParser/Source/ASTInterface.par
       1,109/  1.7%: (AppendNewSequenceTreeToTuples) Line 656 File 371 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/TupleCloneDetector.par
         923/  1.4%: (FindLongestSequenceExistingTupleAndNewTree) Line 368 File 371 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/TupleCloneDetector.par
         851/  1.3%: (CreateSetOfCandidateClones) Line 1170 File 371 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/TupleCloneDetector.par
         771/  1.2%: (FollowSequenceNodePortNthToNode) Line 5369 File 52 c:/DMS/Infrastructure/HyperGraph/Source/Graph.par
         717/  1.1%: (AppendNodeToCandidateList) Line 1101 File 371 C:/DMS/Tools/CloneDR/Source/Server/TupleCloneDetector.par
         707/  1.1%: (Lookup) Line 368 File 339 c:/DMS/Domains/PARLANSE/Library/HashTables/hash.par
```

This program climbs over abstract syntax trees a lot.  And you can see it: the hot spot is "GetFirstChild" (climbing down the tree) with 12% of the CPU.  The top 20 functions account for most of the work;  I would guess these functions comprise maybe 1000 lines of code.  Everything else is 1% or lower, and this is a 500K line application.

This is only one measurement.  I think its performance profile reflects many applications in general.  OTOH, this is a symbolic computation over compiler data structures, so it is hardly typical of what gets run on the everyday computer.